# Spring Boot JPA many to many removing join table relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Student and an entity Course, and they have many to many relationship, with the Student class being the owner. I'm able to add course for a student but I'm unable to remove a course for a student. I did create a utility method for deleting the connection but it does not work, and I'm not able to find the reason what is wrong. There is no error, it just does nothing.
Maybe anyone encounter anything similar? Thank you in advance

The database schema is a simple many to many relationship
[image]

Here is the Student entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    private Set<Course> courseTaken = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, Set<Course> courseTaken) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.courseTaken = courseTaken;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Set<Course> getCourseTaken() {
        return courseTaken;
    }

    public void setCourseTaken(Set<Course> courseTaken) {
        this.courseTaken = courseTaken;
    }
    
    public void removeCourse(Course tempCourse) {
        courseTaken.remove(tempCourse);
        tempCourse.getStudentAttending().remove(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", courseTaken="
                + courseTaken + "]";
    }       
}
```

Here is a Course entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="course")
public class Course implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name="course_name")
    private String courseName;
    
    @Column(name="course_description")
    private String courseDescription;
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courseTaken")
    private Set<Student> studentAttending  = new HashSet<>();
    
    public Course() {
    }

    public Course(String courseName, String courseDescription, Set<Student> studentAttending) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
        this.studentAttending = studentAttending;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseDescription() {
        return courseDescription;
    }

    public void setCourseDescription(String courseDescription) {
        this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    }

    public Set<Student> getStudentAttending() {
        return studentAttending;
    }
    
    public void setStudentAttending(Set<Student> studentAttending) {
        this.studentAttending = studentAttending;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", courseName=" + courseName + ", courseDescription=" + courseDescription + "]";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where the courses are being deleted from students?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found what I missed, I just forgot to save the changes into DB, student.save was missing. All works.

```
@GetMapping("/deleteCourse")
    public String deleteCourseForStudent(@RequestParam("courseId") Long courseId, @RequestParam("studentId") Long studentId) {
        
        Course tempCourse = courseService.findById(courseId);
        Student tempStudent = studentService.findById(studentId);
        
        tempStudent.removeCourse(tempCourse);
        
        studentService.save(tempStudent);
        
        return "redirect:/student/details?studentId=" + studentId;
    }
```